# move up text view only when virtual keyboard open on android

Tags: android, android-layout

My xml code is here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:id="@+id/toplayout">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:id="@+id/bottomlayout">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter value" />
</LinearLayout>
```

when i execute , i got like this,

[image]

after execute , when i enter the value on edit text ,the virtual keyboard is open and the entire mainlayout is scroll up,  i got like this

[image]

But i except , the top layout not to scroll up , only the bottom layout or textview scroll up. i expect like this,
[image]

how to scroll only the edit view when open the virtual keyboard. ?

Comment: Try by adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" for the activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this; maybe it is useful. Adjust the `manifest` file

```
<activity
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"              
      android:name=".youractivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

@Ganesh you change `manifest` like above your `Activity` code also working

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"   >

  <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/toplayout">
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />   
     <EditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Enter value" />

     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why we want to resize view when soft keyboard is launched?