# Prevent UI Reflow in Android when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, reflow

I have an App called [Countdown Calendar](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.krylonosstudios.countdowncalendar) (It is a widget that counts down the days to events in your Google Calendars; fixing minor bugs atm). But the bug I am trying to fix right now has to do with the UI re-flowing whenever you input text. Let me show you by example. Here is what the UI looks like when the keyboard is NOT out:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when the keyboard is out:

[image]

How do I make it so that the UI does not look terrible when the user attempts to use the keyboard?

Comment: your second image is broken , kindly update

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119967/move-up-text-view-only-when-virtual-keyboard-open-on-android/11120597#11120597

Comment: @Hunt I think that the image should be fixed now? Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without being able to see the second image, I would guess you simply need to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your Activity tag in the manifest to cause your layout to simply pan out of view instead of attempting to rescale to fit the remaining area.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I wanted! You have the answer and my thanks! For anybody else that, like me, was interested in the other options to windowSoftInputMode then see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: or do it from the activity `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Answer (score 2):

Use scrollView as a parentView and set the remaining subview inside it.

Comment: Upvoted because that technically works too but kcoppock's solution was exactly what I was looking for.