# Move up one layout with the soft keyboard but keep one on the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-widget, android-softkeyboard

I have the following TabHost layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_app_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/site_logo_height"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@color/tab_subtitle_background"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/barlogo" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="99"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:tag="done"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

The thing is, when the soft-keyboard appears both the Button and the TabWidget move up.

My objective is to keep the TabWidget on the bottom (below the soft-keyboard) and let the Ok button move up (on the top of the keyboard). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this may be it is use full adjust manifest

```
<activity
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"              
  android:name=".youractivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

see [move up text view only when virtual keyboard open on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119967/move-up-text-view-only-when-virtual-keyboard-open-on-android/11120597#11120597)

Comment: I am already using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` . But what I wanted, when the soft-keyboard pops up, was to keep the TabWidget below the keyboard (fixed at the bottom), and the Button to move with the keyboard (as it is now, using the ajustResize).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"              
    android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: does not work. "keyboardHidden" is a value for android:configChanges and not windowSoftInputMode.