# How to make the keyboard overlap the form field

Tags: android, cordova, textfield, overlapping

Let's say we have a sample form in an Android Phonegap application ([download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/17drxww2mvneb00/Sandbox%20build.zip) source code).

The form has a very long list of input text fields.

Every time we focus input on a field, the keyboard is popup and the focused field is scrolled accordingly so that it sits on the top of the keyboard as below snapshot.

[image]

My question is: How can we make the form remain/not scroll its fields position - i.e. when we focus a field, the popup keyboard will overlap the bottom of the form no matter what fields it is overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Maybe working but not sure [SEE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119967/move-up-text-view-only-when-virtual-keyboard-open-on-android/11120597#11120597)

```
<activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"              
   android:name=".youractivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```