# How Can I force my layout to get pushed up by the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a relativelayout that fills the screen in an activity.  And I launch a softkeyboard with code like this:

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT,InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

It pops up on top of the RelativeLayout, instead of pushing the relativelayout up.  Is there any way I can get the keyboard to do this?  I tried adding    `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my activity in the manifest but this did not help.

Comment: Have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity tag inside manifest?

Comment: Once see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119967/move-up-text-view-only-when-virtual-keyboard-open-on-android/11120597#11120597

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ? Also, it may be because you add a keyboard dynamically. Try and use only edit-text, as it opens the keyboard natively on click