# SoftInputKeyboard pushes the view upwards android

Tags: android

This question has been asked before, but its not working for me. Not even "adjustPan" is working. Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/navbg" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/navtitle" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/navbaricon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share_app"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/moreoptions" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tut_tab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/s13"
        android:textColor="@color/text_patti"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/tab_lines" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downpost_tab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/s14"
        android:textColor="@color/text_patti"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/tab_lines" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downloads_tab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/s15"
        android:textColor="@color/text_patti"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/text_patti"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/downpost_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:background="@color/text_patti"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/downloads_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@color/text_patti"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/tab_lines" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/my_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7574057688734526/7494789493"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" />
```

The admob goes up when keyboard opens. Maybe because of weight in viewpager. Howto avoid it?

Comment: try this may be use full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119967/move-up-text-view-only-when-virtual-keyboard-open-on-android/11120597#11120597

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy I want to prevent the add to go up :)